# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\User\UserAuth\ResetPassswordController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project am trying to imaplement forget password functinality. I succesfully got a password reset email, but when i submit that form which contains new password, its generating this error `Target class [App\Http\Controllers\User\UserAuth\ResetPassswordController] does not exist.`

But there is `ResetPassswordController.php` named file in specified path.

Following is the code of Resetpasswordcontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User\UserAuth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use JsValidator;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $redirectTo = '/user/dashboard';

    protected $validationRules = [
                                        'name' => 'required|max:255',
                                        'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
                                        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
                                    ];


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
       // $this->middleware('user.guest');
    }

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string|null  $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {
        $validator = JsValidator::make($this->validationRules,[],[],'#resetform');
        return view('user.auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email, 'validator' => $validator]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('users');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('user');
    }
}
```

Following is the code in routes (web.php)

```
Route::get('/', 'User\UserAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::get('/register', 'User\UserAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('register');

Route::post('user/login', 'User\UserAuth\LoginController@login')->name('postLogin');
Route::post('user/logout', 'User\UserAuth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

Route::get('user/password/reset', 'User\UserAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('user/password/email', 'User\UserAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.reequest');
Route::post('user/password/reset', 'User\UserAuth\ResetPassswordController@reset')->name('password.email');
Route::get('user/password/reset/{token}', 'User\UserAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
```

Following is the code of form submission, which contains new password

```
<form class="" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/user/password/reset') }}" id="resetform">
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yes i already did that, but issue not resolved

Comment: Because you have 3 's' ResetPassswordController but your class has 2 's' ResetPasswordController. It's just a typo